# Cannot access VueJs instance variable from outside main.js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a country list that is saved as a configuration file `country_list`. The file has the following contents.

```
    export default {
      countries: [
        'AUSTRALIA',
        'AUSTRIA',
        'BELGIUM',
        'BRAZIL',
        'BULGARIA',
        'CANADA',
        'CHINA',
        'CROATIA',
        'CYPRUS',
        'CZECHIA',
        'DENMARK',
        'ESTONIA',
        'FINLAND'
    ]
}
```

Now in the `main.js` file I am importing it and set it as an instance variable

```
import countryList from './config/country_list';

Vue.prototype['$countryData'] = countryList;
```

Now I am trying to access this variable `$countries` in a file called `utils.js` like the following :

```
export const checkCountryIncluded = (country) => {

    const countries = this.$countryData.countries;
    
    return countries.includes(country);
}
```

and this `checkCountryIncluded` is called from a component.

But here I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'countries' of undefined`

I am new to VueJS and it will be helpful if someone can point out what is missing here.

Comment: Try `import * as countryList` ? Otherwise you can also do `export const countries = [ ... ];` then `import { countries } from './config/country_list';`

Comment: I think you need to show where you are writing the `const countries =...` line

Comment: I am using it in a `utils.js` file. I need to import `main.js` file here ?

Comment: @JeremyThille I tried it, but it is showing the same error.

Comment: the function in `utils.js` file which uses `const countries = this.$countryData.countries` when do you call it?

Comment: So, I have a component called `Customers.vue` and there is one variable named as `isCountryIncluded`. The call is like `this.isCountryIncluded = checkCountryIncluded(this.country)`. I have the above code inside `checkCountryIncluded` function, which is in `utils.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In separated files like utils the vue instance is not available, it's only available in the components hierarchy, the solution is to pass that global data as parameter when you call your utility function :

```
this.isCountryIncluded = checkCountryIncluded(this.$countryData,this.country)
```

utils.js :

```
export const checkCountryIncluded = (countryData,country) => {

    const countries = countryData.countries;
    
    return countries.includes(country);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `checkCountryIncluded`  with the component context.

```
this.isCountryIncluded = checkCountryIncluded.apply(this, [this.country])
```

For this to work, the function should be a normal function (non-arrow) since you cannot change the context of arrow functions.

```
export const checkCountryIncluded = function(country) {

    const countries = this.$countryData.countries;
    
    return countries.includes(country);
}
```